# Select data from comment column

Tags: mysql

I have a table where the program get data from the comment column. I'd show this in a select query. Table contains `a_id`, `a_timestamp`, `a_mode`, `a_comment`. The a_mode listed from the a_comment (don't know, how), like:

- 0 is Amode
- 1 is Bmode
- 2 is Cmode.

I can list theese datas:

```
SELECT a_id, a_timestamp, a_mode FROM table WHERE a_id > 100;
```

Result:

```
100, 2019-03-13, 1
101, 2019-03-13, 2
```

I'd list datas like this:

```
a_id, a_timestamp, a_mode
100, 2019-03-13, Bmode
101, 2019-03-13, Cmode
```

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand what you want

Comment: Do you mean you need to just change the column name? like `SELECT a_id, a_timestamp, a_comment as 'a_mode' FROM table WHERE a_id > 100;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT a_id, a_timestamp, 
    CASE a_mode
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Amode'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Bmode'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Cmode'
    END as a_mode
FROM table
WHERE a_id > 100
```